# Magento 2.2.6 CSS JS not loading in admin panel after changing base and custom admin URLs

Tags: admin, css, base-url

It's a multi store site in development and I changed the test URL to one of the production URLs for the default Base URLs and one of the store Base URLs. I also changed the option to Use Custom Admin URL from Yes to No.

All static content has been deleted and redeployed and cache flushed. The frontend is loading OK with CSS. The admin login page comes up, and I can log in, but with no CSS.

Any help with resolving this much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by my hosting provider. They set the media/static URLs to retrieve from the main virtual host rather than being left empty.